# contact form in wordpress with custom pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to do sign-up/login on my website but I can not understand how to do it because I'm trying to do a wordpress theme and in my theme there isn't widget setion. I've already created template pages and I want to integrate those pages.
Help me

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Sign in and Sign Up in Custom WP Theme**

Here is the form fields which you can edit later on according to your requirement.

You have user_nick_name which can be used as username.
Email and then password in last submit button.

```
<form id="sign_up_form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="user_nickname" name="user_nickname" placeholder="Enter user desire username" />
    <input type="text" id="user_email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
    <input id="user_pass" name="user_pass" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <input type="submit" value="Register now" />
</form>
```

You need to place below code in JS file this Code will help you to generate Ajax Request.

**Important Note:** I have added below code in ajax-signup-script.js which i have placed in js folder make sure you keep the same name in order to proceed with same code, if you want to rename this file you will also need to replace this from one more place to get things working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    "use strict";

 // Sign Up
 $('form#sign_up_form').on('submit', function(e){
    $('form#sign_up_form p.status').show().text(ajax_signup_object.loadingmessage);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_signup_object.ajaxurl,
        data: { 
            'action': 'custom_signup', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
            'nickname': $('form#sign_up_form #user_nickname').val(), 
            'user_email': $('form#sign_up_form #user_email').val(), 
            'user_pass': $('form#sign_up_form #user_pass').val() },
        success: function(data){
            $('form#sign_up_form p.status').text(data.message);
            if (data.signup == true){
                document.location.href = ajax_signup_object.redirecturl;
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Almost finished what we have started you need to place this code in functions.php.

```
  function wordpress_custom_signup_function(){

    //Get Defined Role by WordPress
    $default_role = get_option('default_role');

    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];       

    //Check For the NickName Empty
    if(isset($nickname) && $nickname <> ''){
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'    => $nickname,
            'user_email'  => $user_email,
            'user_pass'  => $user_pass,
            'role' => $default_role
        );
        $exists = email_exists($user_email);
        $user_signup = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        if ( !$exists ){
            if ( is_wp_error($user_signup) ){
                echo json_encode(array('signup'=>false, 'message'=>esc_attr__('Please verify the details you are providing.','custom-theme')));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('signup'=>true, 'message'=>esc_attr__('Your request submitted successfully, Redirecting you to login page!','custom-theme')));
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('signup'=>false, 'message'=>'Notice: Email already exists!'.$exists.''));            
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('signup'=>false, 'message'=>esc_attr__('Please verify the details you are providing.','custom-theme')));
    }

    die();
}   

 function custom_function_for_signup(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-signup-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ajax-signup-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-signup-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-signup-script', 'ajax_signup_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => esc_url(admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )),
        'redirecturl' => esc_url(home_url()),
        'loadingmessage' => esc_attr__('Sending user info, please wait...','custom-theme')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action('wp_ajax_custom_signup', 'wordpress_custom_signup_function');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_signup', 'wordpress_custom_signup_function' );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_function_for_signup');
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you add this code so that i could help you with it?

Comment: Sure.. I create new file.php where I paste your html code.. after this I create a new doc js with your doc's name and paste your js.. and after in the 'function.php ` I paste  ur function.. when I've done all.. create a new wp page and I see only html.. when I put data don't happens nothing

Comment: I have edited the code you might be missing the document.ready code which i have added you need to update that in your js file. Make sure you run this in chrome and check the console tab in case of any error let me know.